# Update value in a unix text file

Tags: bash, file, unix, text, sed

My input text file (abc.txt) is as follows,

```
2013-10-15 00:58:59.2557431|Florida|12345|
```

I need the output text as follows

```
2013-10-15 00:58:59.2557431|2013-10-15|Florida|12345|
```

That is, I need the date part alone to be extracted and added as second field in output text file.

Comment: `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `c`, `c++`, and probably lots more. What do you *know* as far as languages?

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/([^ ]*) ([^|]*)/\1 \2|\1/' file
2013-10-15 00:58:59.2557431|2013-10-15|Florida|12345|
2013-11-19 10:58:59.2544743|2013-11-19|Chicago|92345|
2013-12-19 11:58:59.2517431|2013-12-19|Ohio|13335|
```

It catches the block up to space `(1)` and up to the pipe `(2)` and then prints `(1) (2)|(1)`.

It can also be done with awk, taking two different field separators (| and space), but then you have to specify every output field separator, so it makes the final result a little bit ugly to read.

Comment: A space after date is lost.

Comment: Corrected `sed`version: `sed -r 's/([^ ]*) ([^|]*)/\1 \2|\1/'`

Comment: Uhms, sure @Jotne, didn't see it. Thanks for informing! No need to downvote, though.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `awk`

```
awk -F\| '{split($1,a," ");$2=a[1] OFS $2}1' OFS=\|
2013-10-15 00:58:59.2557431|2013-10-15|Florida|12345|
```

Comment: Good idea. As they are the same, you can also use `BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"}`.

Comment: I know, but mine is less to type :) Can also use at the end `FS=\| OFS=\|`

Comment: But if it happens to have another field delimiter, you have to type twice to change it :)